# setTimeout wait for setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I stumbled upon a problem:
the code is supposed to output "hi1" "hi2" "hi3" "hi4" in that order.
I wrote this simplified code, the actual code is more complicated and causes me to not be able to remove some of the functions I marked.

```
function test() {
    console.log("hi2");
    setTimeout(function () { //maybe replace this?
    console.log("hi3");
    }, 2000);
}

console.log("hi1");
test();
setTimeout(function () { //cannot get rid of this
    console.log("hi4");
}, 0);
```

how do I make it output in order?

Comment: Why have you tagged `jQuery`?

Comment: `setTimeout` is asynchronous, the order in which you write your statements is not the order they get executed. If you want to wait for something to finish you have to use callbacks, or promises (a nice way to chain callbacks).

Comment: `setTimeout(function () { //cannot get rid of this`  Why??? You should explain it instead

Answer (score 1):

If you need to wait for `setTimeout` in your `test()` to execute before continuing, the easiest way is to use callback:

```
function test(callback) {
    console.log("hi2");
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("hi3");
        // Execute additional logics
        callback();
    }, 2000);
}

console.log("hi1");
test(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("hi4");
    }, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the callback or try to show your complicated code is more. We can help you to analyze it.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out setTimeout is asynchronous so they run in the background while the rest of the code continues. I'd guess that at the moment you get something like:

```
hi1
hi2
hi4
then a 2000ms delay, then
hi3
```

If you can't change the code much then try changing the delay for hi4 to 4000 like:

```
setTimeout(function () { //cannot get rid of this
    console.log("hi4");
}, 4000);
```

That should fix the order, but it's still pretty messy and unreliable. I'd rather have something like:

```
function showMessage(msg, delay) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(msg);
    }, delay);
}
showMessage('hi1', 0);
showMessage('hi2', 2000);
showMessage('hi3', 4000);
showMessage('hi4', 6000);
```